# Asynctask#1 An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, email

i am receiving mails from server,Progress dialog is showed while getting mails,when i get all the mails the dialog closes and i couldnt reach to my listview where i want to show mails and it gives me exception,here is code.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Inb.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Getting mails...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //Do something...
            try {
                publishProgress(arg0);
                adopter=new List(Inb.this,getMessages());

            } catch (MessagingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.setAdapter(adopter);
            return null;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                pd.dismiss();
        }

    };
    task.execute();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent in=new Intent(Inb.this,EmailView.class);
        Globals.message=messageList.get(arg2);
    /// in.putExtra("messagedetail",messageList.get(arg2));
        startActivity(in);
    }
});}


public ArrayList<Message> getMessages() throws MessagingException,IOException{
    Folder folder = null;
    Store store = null;
    String usname="";
    String passw="";

    try {
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
      session.setDebug(true);
      store = session.getStore("imaps");

      //For Hotmail Mailbox inbox messages
      //store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com",emaill, pww);
      //For Yahoo Mailbox inbox messages
      //store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com",emaill, pww);
      //For Google Mailbox Inbox messages
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com",usname, passw);
    folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      /* Others GMail folders :
       * [Gmail]/All Mail   This folder contains all of your Gmail messages.
       * [Gmail]/Drafts     Your drafts.
       * [Gmail]/Sent Mail  Messages you sent to other people.
       * [Gmail]/Spam       Messages marked as spam.
       * [Gmail]/Starred    Starred messages.
       * [Gmail]/Trash      Messages deleted from Gmail.
       */
      folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
      messageList.clear();
     int n=folder.getMessageCount();
     for(int i=n-1,j=1;j!=20;j++,i--)
     {
        Message msg= folder.getMessage(i);

        msg.getSubject();
      messageList.add(msg);
     }
    return messageList;
    }
    finally {
      if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
      if (store != null && store.isConnected()) { store.close(); }
    }
```

and this is my log

```
12-20 21:37:58.551:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-20 21:37:58.551:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):Process: com.minio, PID: 1568
12-20 21:37:58.551:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):java.lang.RuntimeException:An error occured while executing doInBackground()    
12-20 21:37:58.551android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-20 21:37:58.551:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):atjava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
21:37:58.551:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):atjava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7062)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3118)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:698)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10482)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:7172)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:915)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:503)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at com.minio.Inb$1.doInBackground(Inb.java:85)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at com.minio.Inb$1.doInBackground(Inb.java:1)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-20 21:37:58.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     ... 4 more
12-20 21:37:59.621: E/OpenGLRenderer(1568): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.minio.Inbox has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e11b090 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1002,486} that was originally added here
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:457)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:277)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at com.minio.Inb$1.onPreExecute(Inb.java:67)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at com.minio.Inb.onCreate(Inb.java:99)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2404)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:769)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:428)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:255)
 12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):     at com.minio.Inbox.onCreate(Inbox.java:76)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
12-20 21:37:59.651: E/WindowManager(1568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line : `list.setAdapter(adopter);` in `doInBackground` will throw an error - you can't touch the Main UI thread from a background thread, instead you should be passing a result (in your case a List) to `OnPostExecute` and updating the adapter there (`OnPostExecute` runs in the Main UI thread).

Comment: Thanks alot Solved :)